# iOS app in SpriteKit using Swift lags after 6 minutes, any ideas why?

Tags: ios, performance, swift, sprite-kit

I have been working on an app in SpriteKit that displays a new image after every gesture from the user. During each session, the images are inevitably `removedFromParent()` but the user calls them frequently.

After using my app for about 6 minutes though, I noticed that it starts to get...choppy. The gestures I have set up use swiping but for some reason when I tap the screen a lot the CPU usage shoots up to 104%?!?

After every swipe, I call this code:

```
    var chooseImage:String = imageCollection[Int(arc4random() % 16)]
    var swiperImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: chooseImage)
    swiperImage.position = nodePosition
    swiperImage.xScale = SH * 0.002
    swiperImage.yScale = SH * 0.002
    addChild(swiperImage)
```

This is part of the code that gets called after every swipe I make. Could this be a memory leak? I am at a total loss.

This is is the CPU usage result:[image]

Comment: Try doing some performance analysis with instruments?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing an array of `String`s you should try storing the `SKTexture`s for those images. These textures would be created when the object you referenced code from is instantiated. Then you can use those textures to instantiate the nodes later, reducing the amount of unnecessary image loading each time a node is created. It would look something like:

```
let imageTextures = imageCollection.map { SKTexture(imageNamed: $0) }
...
let swiperImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: imageTextures[Int(arc4random_uniform(imageTextures.count))]
```

Additionally, you can use `arc4random_uniform()` to generate a "uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound" instead of using the mod.

This solution also has the benefit of letting you have multiple nodes use the same texture without having to reload it for each node.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I started programming a month ago so I'm still pretty new but this sounds like it would solve the problem. Curious, using this method, how would I check which string was passed to generate the texture? I had conditionals that checked chooseImage but with this method, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: What were you doing that depended on the file name? In any case, you do not have to discard the array of names. The array of textures will be in the same order as those in your name array, so you could store the result of the random number generation and use that to access the string also. Another option would to be create a `struct` that had two properties: the file name and the texture. Then store instances of those structs.

Comment: Ok so I figured out how to check my conditional but the problem still exists? In fact, my screen jitters whenever I tap it or try to interact with it, if I let it be everything runs smoothly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the `SKView`'s `showsNodeCount` property set to `true`? That will at least tell you how many nodes are in the scene. If you have a high number, then you will possibly get a performance issue, but I don't know what that number would be (probably varies depending on a number of conditions).

Comment: I do, in fact, I have a condition that checks node count and makes sure it doesn't go below 2. It usually is around 3 - 4 every session...I do call removeFromParent() for every node that gets generated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you clear the child of your parents before you add a new one.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Because every node I make from swiping gets removeFromParent() on it..